# I clone dailymotion-sdk-android-dev to my PC, and try to run it in Android Studio, but I keep getting Gradle Sync Issue

Tags: android, dailymotion-api

This is the Gradle Sync Issue.

Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Software\Dailymotion\dailymotion-sdk-android-dev\sampleapp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

However, my distributionUrl is https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties file.

**My Android Studio version is 2.2.3.**

Can anyone help me out?

My build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
    }
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16

        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream("sampleapp.properties"))
        //props.load(project.rootProject.file('sampleapp.properties').newDataInputStream())

        buildConfigField "String", "apiKey", props.getProperty("apiKey")
        buildConfigField "String", "apiSecret", props.getProperty("apiSecret")
        buildConfigField "String", "defaultLogin", props.getProperty("defaultLogin")
        buildConfigField "String", "defaultPassword", props.getProperty("defaultPassword")

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':sdk')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

Also, this is build.gradle file for sdk

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    // for io.kickflip.sdk
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your project-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Under project settings -> Gradle make sure you have selected `Use default gradle wrapper`

Comment: I update build.gradle file in my question.

Comment: It is default gradle wrapper.